# Uploadify dropdown folder list

Tags: ajax, drop-down-menu, directory, uploadify

I'm using the ajax uploader Uploadify which is realy great!
i managed to get a dropdown list with the folders in some directory but it writes on the parant dir..

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : 'uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : 'uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder'        :   '../albums/<?php echo $_POST[folderchoose]  ?>',
    'multi'       : true,
    'auto'      : true,
    'displayData': 'speed',
  });

});
```

index.php

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<select name="folderchoose" id="folderchoose">

<?php
$items = glob("../albums/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
{
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
         ?>  <option><? echo "$item\n "; ?></option> <?
        }
    }

?>
</select>
</form>
<input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" />
<a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload();">Upload Files</a>
```

it works except it uploads the files to "albums/"

thanks ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using PHP to set the folder variable in your upload parameters object.  PHP is server-side, not client-side.  Therefore, it isn't executed until the page loads.  Your path ends up being `../albums/`.

Also, this is an incredibly insecure way to handle your file uploads.  Clients should not be able to pick what paths to put files... at least, not without sanitation of this path.

What I would do minimally is change this line, to this:

```
'folder'        :   $('#folderchoose').val()
```

And then, server-side, concat `../albums` or whatever the path is.  Again though, sanitize your input.  Who cares if it is just for admins or not.  Admins can be evil too, and so can scripts and others that get their password.